# Is there an operator which is the opposite of mergeMap()?

Tags: http, rxjs, observable

We have a case where we only want one HTTP request to go out at a time and only want to allow retry or call again if the pending call either succeeds or fails. We've been doing the classic wrap it in a boolean but were wondering if there was an operator for it. My hunch is no.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need `switchMap`. It will only subscribe to the last value of the external observable and it will map it to an internal observable. With switchMap, its possible to cancel previous http requests on the fly.

For more info take a look in the [following link](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what we want. We always want the first request not the last. I've used switchMap() implementing the classic case of autocomplete. Imagine a situation where the server will give out a job but the handler is only allowed 2 pending jobs to work on at one time. Once the request goes out, you don't want a slow one for example to actually complete and dispense a job to the agent that's already working on two jobs. Thanks for the reply though.